# How can I convert the datetime intervals into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, intervals

I would like to make a dataframe of dates with an interval of a week. I have used the following codes to generate a list of dates but when I want to make this into a dataframe, I got this error:

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Could you give me a hlep?

```
import pandas as pd

from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

def perdelta(start, end, delta):
    curr = start
    while curr < end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta

for dates in perdelta(date(1997, 7, 19), date(2020, 5, 25), timedelta(days=7)):
    OP_dates = pd.DataFrame(dates)


print(OP_dates.head(3))
```

Comment: What's your expected output?Do you want  all weekly dates  in the interval starting from `1997, 7, 19` to `2020, 5, 25`?

Comment: Read about https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need a loop here:

```
OP_dates = pd.DataFrame(perdelta(date(1997, 7, 19), date(2020, 5, 25), timedelta(days=7)))
```

Using a loop:

```
OP_dates = pd.DataFrame()
for dates in perdelta(date(1997, 7, 19), date(2020, 5, 25), timedelta(days=7)):
    OP_dates = pd.DataFrame.append(OP_dates, [dates])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)?  I believe this does exactly what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

date_range = pd.date_range('7-19-1997','5-25-2020',freq='1W')

#if you want the dates as entries
df = pd.DataFrame(date_range)

#or if you want the dates as the index:
df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range)
```

Looks like someone just posted a fix using your `perdelta` function which also works - the issue was that your `for` loop tried to make a DataFrame for each date yielded from `perdelta` rather than making a single DataFrame for a collection/array of the dates yielded by `perdelta`.

JSYK you can also use `datetimes` with `pandas.date_range`, instead of the time strings I used.